# Create a list of buttons divided in 3 rows

Tags: html, css, menu, row

I wanted a responsive-centered menu of several tabs divided into three rows, and keeping the three rows for mobile.
I tried:

```css
.flex-container {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: row;
                text-align: center;
                gap: 16px;
                justify-content: center;
            }

            /* Responsive layout - makes a row responsive or one column-layout instead of two-column layout */
            @media (max-width: 800px) {
                .flex-container {
                    flex-direction: row;
                    flex-direction: column;
                    
                }
            }
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12" style="margin-bottom: 10em;">

<div class="flex-container"> 
<p><a class="btn btn-default" href=")" role="button">Poverty</a></p> 
<p><a class="btn btn-default" href="" role="button">Water</a></p>       
<p><a class="btn btn-default" href="" role="button">Disasters</a></p> </div>

<div class="flex-container"> 
<p><a class="btn btn-default" href=")" role="button">Poverty</a></p> 
<p><a class="btn btn-default" href="" role="button">Water</a></p>        
<p><a class="btn btn-default" href="" role="button">Disasters</a></p> </div>

<div class="flex-container"> 
<p><a class="btn btn-default" href=")" role="button">Poverty</a></p> 
<p><a class="btn btn-default" href="" role="button">Water</a></p>       
<p><a class="btn btn-default" href="" role="button">Disasters</a></p> </div>

</div>
```

I did it like the one below, but it seemed a mess... It works, but there might be better options regarding structure than dividing a menu into three flex containers... Do you have any better ideas?

This is what I want: a responsive centered menu composed of 3 rows

[image: Screen Shot]

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways to do it than this one I am suggesting.

But if you have always a fixed number of items by row. you can use flex-basis to break the items to the next row and flex-wrap to have the same effect without having 3 containers.

```css
.break {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  text-align: center;
  column-gap: 16px;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}


/* Responsive layout - makes a row responsive or one column-layout instead of two-column layout */

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .flex-container {
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12" style="margin-bottom: 10em;">

  <div class="flex-container">
    <p><a class="btn btn-default" href=")" role="button">Poverty</a></p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="" role="button">Water</a></p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="" role="button">Disasters</a></p>
    <div class="break"></div>

    <p><a class="btn btn-default" href=")" role="button">Poverty</a></p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="" role="button">Water</a></p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="" role="button">Disasters</a></p>
    <div class="break"></div>


    <p><a class="btn btn-default" href=")" role="button">Poverty</a></p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="" role="button">Water</a></p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="" role="button">Disasters</a></p>
    <div class="break"></div>

  </div>
```

you can also just use flex wrap, and the items will stack up but the number of items will vary per row.